# Python quiz, need guidance

Tags: python, compare

This is my first code so if you could bear with me and be as thorough as possible.

This quiz asks a question and has 4 possible answers which you choose 1-4. the file which it reads from looks like this. the right answer is displayed above the question.

```
A
Which sport uses the term LOVE ?
A)Tennis
B)Golf
C)Football
D)Swimming
B
What is the German word for WATER ?
A)Wodar
B)Wasser
C)Werkip
D)Waski
```

What i want to do is grab this chunk without the answer to the question which it does now, only the questions and the possible answers. And when you guess it will compare your answer with the real answer to see if it matches, if it does you'll get a score and if it doesn't you don't. My biggest queries are how to compare it and get these chunks without its answer.

```
quiz_file = '/home/wryther/Desktop/QUIZ.DAT'
num_questions = 146

def get_chunk(buf, n):

    while buf:
        chunk = [buf.readline() for _ in range(n)]

         if not any(chunk):
             chunk = None

         yield chunk

def get_awns(ans):  #This transfomrs the ints answers to str so it could compare if its right or wrong.
   if ans == 1:
         ans = 'A'
    elif ans == 2:
         ans = 'B'
    elif ans == 3:
         ans = 'C'
    elif ans == 4:
         ans = 'D'



with open(quiz_file) as quiz_contents:

    choices = [None] * num_questions

    i = 0

    for chunk in get_chunk(quiz_contents, 6):
            if not chunk:
            break

            print()
            for line in chunk:
            print(line)

            choices[i] = int(input("1   3\n2    4?\n:"))
            get_awns(choices[i])
```

I appreciate all replies, whether it's criticism, tips or help, if it's relevant to my subject.

Comment: _this is my first code so if you could bare with me_: Not _bare_, but _bear_.  Please.

Comment: In each `chunk`, `chunk[0]` is the answer key, `chunk[1]` is the question and `chunk[2:]` the answer text lines

Comment: Thanks gee helped alot! Any idea how I can compare chunk[0] to their answer and add points? that would be sweet, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your answer correctly, your question is about how to separate within each chunk the question from the answers. As @jonrsharpe commented, you have to access the items of each chunk separately. Either using subscripts as jonrsharpe said, or you can unpack them directly.

```
def readChunk(buf, n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield next(buf).strip() #get rid of newlines

with open('questions.txt', 'r') as lines:
    while True:
        try:
            #Unpacking into separate values
            correct, question, *answers = readChunk(lines, 6)
        except ValueError:
            #End of file
            break
        print('The question is', question)
        print('And the answers are', answers)
        print('And the correct answers is', answers[ord(correct) - ord('A')])
```

---

Using your sample file, this snippet outputs:

```
The question is Which sport uses the term LOVE ?
And the answers are ['A)Tennis', 'B)Golf', 'C)Football', 'D)Swimming']
And the correct answers is A)Tennis
The question is What is the German word for WATER ?
And the answers are ['A)Wodar', 'B)Wasser', 'C)Werkip', 'D)Waski']
And the correct answers is B)Wasser
```